# scheme call from JS (web browser) to android activity doesn't update the intent with the scheme data in the url string

Tags: android, url, android-activity, browser, url-scheme

I am launching my app from the browser and if the app is not already loaded/running then it launches the app through onCreate and collects the intent.data and does the right thing.  If the app is already running then launching the app from the browser bypasses the onCreate and goes right to onResume which I "believe" is expected behavior.  But the intent.data associated with the launch from the browser is null.  I was hoping that the intent data would be overwritten with the new intent data from scheme url string so that I can relaunch the webview inside the app with the new parameters.  Is there some way that I can push this new data into the app when it is launched (i.e., resumed) by the browser?

// JS Browser code with arguments to be passed to the app.

```
var r = Math.random();
window.open("myScheme://caca.com/?mode=driver" + "&ec=" + ec + "&uh=" + $("#userHandle").val() + "&at=0" + "&random=" + r);
```

// Xamarin

```
onResume(...) {

    ...

    try
    {

        // currentActivity.Intent.Data != null if app is not already running
        // is null if already running

        Android.Net.Uri data = currentActivity.Intent.Data;
        string scheme = data.Scheme;

        DebugToast("scheme " + scheme, ToastLength.Long);

        if (scheme == "myScheme")
        {
            // force the cookies so the web app will come up as we specify

            SetStorageValue("browserLaunched", "true");
            SetStorageValue("mode", data.GetQueryParameter("mode"));
            SetStorageValue("ec", data.GetQueryParameter("ec"));
            SetStorageValue("uh", data.GetQueryParameter("uh"));
            SetStorageValue("authToken", data.GetQueryParameter("at"));
            SetStorageValue("at", data.GetQueryParameter("at"));

            DebugToast("parms " + data.GetQueryParameter("mode") + " " +  data.GetQueryParameter("ec") + " " + data.GetQueryParameter("uh") + " " +  data.GetQueryParameter("at"), ToastLength.Long);

            // restart the web view with arguments above

            ...

        }
    }
    catch
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Homer Simpson D'oh!.  Needed to add 'onNewIntent()' to activity which receives the "um er dah" new Intent with the appropriate data attached.